# Union / Struct (ARM) - Memory Space Assignation

Tags: c, struct, stm32, unions, keil

Good moorning,

I am trying to create a struct of date of this style:

//Struct 1

```
union{
    struct{
        union{
            struct{
                bool interrupt_receive;
                bool fifo_mode;
                bool enable;
                bool bits_14_mode;
                bool int_source_readed;
                bool void6;
                                bool void7;
                                bool void8;
            };
            unsigned char registro;
        }REG_CTRL_FLG;

        union{
            struct{
                unsigned int REG_CTRL_TIMEH;
                unsigned int REG_CTRL_TIMEL;
            };
            unsigned short REG_CTRL_TIME;
        };

        unsigned int threshold; //Para pruebas pendiente de eliminar
        
        //AXIS_STRUCT data_axis;   
        //AXIS_EXTEND_STRUCT data_full_axis;
    }registros_acelerometro;
    unsigned int registro[3];
}ACELEROMETRO;
```

//Struct 2

```
typedef union{
    
    struct{

        unsigned char dlc_0;

        union{
            struct{
                unsigned char p15:1;
                unsigned char p14:1;
                unsigned char p13:1;
                unsigned char p12:1;
                unsigned char p11:1;
                unsigned char p10:1;
                unsigned char p9:1;             
                unsigned char p8:1;

                unsigned char p7:1;
                unsigned char p6:1;
                unsigned char p5:1;
                unsigned char p4:1;
                unsigned char p3:1;
                unsigned char p2:1;
                unsigned char p1:1;
                unsigned char p0:1;
            };
            unsigned short p;
        }pulsadores;

        union{
            struct{
                unsigned char lb0:1;
                unsigned char lb1:1;
                unsigned char ls0:1;
                unsigned char ls1:1;
                unsigned char iluminacion:1;
                unsigned char completo:1;
                unsigned char sobrecarga:1;
                unsigned char void7:1;
            }registro_cabina;
        unsigned char estado_cabina;
        };

        unsigned char dlc_4;

    }registros_can_data;

    unsigned char can_data[5];
}TRESA_PULS;
```

The struct 1, i have been used with a STM32F7, ARM Compiler 6.11, and a Keil MDK 5.21, without any problem, but with the configuration that i use in the struct 2, it causes me some problems

The unions that contained int the structure, seem need a aditional memory space to work, which distorts the structure.

I've been thinking about it, but i dont find the error

Do you know if anything has changed?
Is there a pre-processing order that should be used?
Has it happened to any of you?
Do you see any trouble?

Thanks for your help and time.
Kinds Regards.

Comment: Check `sizeof(short)` on your platform.

Comment: Also, note that `p` falls on an unaligned memory address, which means that the compiler likely adds padding before `p`. You may need to use `pragma pack` (see [here](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_chr1384946440202.htm)).

Comment: `union{
            struct{
                unsigned int REG_CTRL_TIMEH;
                unsigned int REG_CTRL_TIMEL;
            };
            unsigned short REG_CTRL_TIME;` is suspicious.  Explain more what this code is attempting to do.

Comment: Perhaps `bool interrupt_receive;` should be a single-bit bit-field member `bool interrupt_receive:1;` and the same for the other members?

Comment: learn about __attribute__((packed))

Comment: Too many nested unions & structs... Whatever you're trying to do, I believe there must be a better & cleaner way.